# Android Progress dialog 0/100-how to remove that

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the text in progressBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895272/how-to-remove-the-text-in-progressbar-in-android)

I have basic issue, I have used default progress dialog and everything works fine. Below the progress bar I have 0% displayed and 0/100 shown but some how they are at the same end next to each other. How do I change this, I just need one of them for starters.  I know I can go in for custom dialog, but for this minor change I did not want to opt for custom dialog.  Is there any way to do this or is custom is the only way ?

```
operationInProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(StartOpScreen.this);
            operationInProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            operationInProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.operation_in_progressdialog));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using API level < 11 then custom is the only way. Starting with API level 11 you can call:

```
setProgressNumberFormat()  // or
setProgressPercentFormat()
```

To change the way these fields are displayed. Including hiding them altogether.

The docs always help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Comment: Thank you , i am using 8 ..but this is a good information that'll keep in mind