# How to remove the text in progressBar in Android?

Tags: android

I have a progress bar in my app but it is showing some text default i want to remove the text. please help me how to remove the text.

Here is my code snippet:

```
ProgressDialog progDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProgressBarExample.this);        
progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progDialog.setMax(200);
progDialog.setMessage("Dollars in checking account:");
progDialog.setButton("Cancel",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
progDialog.show();
```

here is a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
progDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
progDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
```

Comment: These methods seems to be not there in the sdk version 8

Comment: If you're seeing that text on api levels that don't support these methods, then you probably need to make your own dialog and stick a progress bar in the dialog's layout

Comment: These code not working well for all API level, if API is < 14 this code might not work proper.

Answer (score 4):

extra info:

// wrong way

```
progDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null); // NullPointerException !!!
progDialog.show();
```

// right way

```
progDialog.show();
progDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
```

Comment: This is important. It might work on your test devices in the wrong way, but crashes sometimes

Answer (score 4):

Create this class for **Android < API Level 11** and use it instead the default ProgressDialog. It uses reflection to set the visbility to GONE:

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        Method method = TextView.class.getMethod("setVisibility",
                Integer.TYPE);

        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getSuperclass()
                .getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mProgressNumber")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                TextView textView = (TextView) field.get(this);
                method.invoke(textView, View.GONE);
            }

            if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mProgressPercent")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                TextView textView = (TextView) field.get(this);
                method.invoke(textView, View.GONE);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "Failed to invoke the progressDialog method 'setVisibility' and set 'mProgressNumber' to GONE.",
                e);
    }
}
}
```